# Firebase cloud storage quota has been exceeded for this project error

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

As I know firebase gives free quota for cloud storage, and it gives 1GB/per day to download. But my quota has exceeded yesterday(1st of September) and Today is (2nd of September) and Free quota should renew by the next day. But I'm getting the error -

> Could not load files; quota has been exceeded for this project

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cloud Storage daily free allowance resets at midnight pacific standard time (which happens to be where I live).  As I write this, it is 9:41pm Sep 1, so it is not yet Sep 2.  You'll have to wait a few more hours.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. Can I know, Why firebase doesn't use there cloud storage location region time instead of pacific time?

Comment: I don't know how Google determines its billing.  You should reach out to Firebase support for billing questions that are not addressed in the documentation.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: i was checking every minute to make it work, and to my surprise it worked.!! cheers